# Akkusativ oder Nominativ an Position 1?

Tags: word-order, accusative, nominative

Hier ist eine Verwendung des Akkusatives:

> Ich habe **den** Stuhl zum Tisch geschoben.

Das Beispiel ist mir völlig klar, aber wenn ich die Reihenfolge der Wörter im Satz ändern möchte, muss ich das Nomen im Akkusativ oder im Nominativ benutzen?

> **Den** Stuhl habe ich zum Tisch geschoben.
>   
> *oder*
>   **Der** Stuhl habe ich zum Tisch geschoben.

Comment: The word order doesn't affect the case.

Comment: The point of using grammatical cases is to not rely on the word order to identify subject, object, etc., and hence allow for more flexibility in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Subjekt ist in diesem Satz "ich". Die Satzstellung hat keinen Einfluss auf den Fall (Kasus). Richtig ist also nur

> **Den** Stuhl habe ich zum Tisch geschoben.

Answer (score 3):

Im Gegensatz zu vielen anderen Sprachen, darunter Englisch, sind in Deutsch die grammatischen Funktionen der Bestandteile eines Satzes nicht durch die Position bestimmt. Deutsch verwendet zur Kennzeichnung grammatischer Funktionen grammatische Fälle und Präpositionalgruppen, die in vielerlei Hinsicht den Fällen gleichkommen.

Vereinfacht lässt sich über deutsche Aussage-Hauptsätze folgendes sagen:

1. An Position 2 des Satzes steht immer ein Teil des Prädikats. Wenn das Prädikat nur aus einem Vollverb besteht, steht dieses Vollverb an Position 2, sonst das Hilfsverb (das Vollverb steht in diesem Fall am Ende des Satzes).
2. Die andern Bestandteile des Satzen dürfen (fast) überall im Satz stehen. Es gibt aber Einschränkungen, auf die ich hier nicht im Detail eingehe. Trotzdem ist die Wahl der Position wesentlich freier als z.B. in Englisch.
3. Das Subjekt steht immer im Nominativ. Daraus folgt: Wenn nur ein Bestandteil des Satzes im Nominativ steht, ist dieser Teil das Subjekt. Wenn mehr als zwei Bestandteile im Nominativ stehen, liegt meist ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ vor. In diesem Fall ist nicht ganz klar, was das Subjekt ist.

Was heißt das in deinem Beispiel?

Das Prädikat deines Satzes ist »*habe geschoben*«. Dabei ist »*habe*« ein Hilfsverb (eine Form von *sein*), »*geschoben*« ist das Vollverb (eine Form von *schieben*). Nach Regel 1 muss gelten:

> <sub>*pos_1*</sub> **habe** <sub>[*pos_3* [*pos_4* [...]]]</sub> **geschoben**.

Das Prädikat eines Satzes liefert übrigens die Information, *was* im Satz passiert. (Es wird *geschoben*.)

Die weiteren Satzglieder sind:

- **ich**
  Das ist ein Personalpronomen im **Nominativ**.
  Da dieses Satzglied das einzige ist, das im Nominativ steht, ist dieses Wort das Subjekt des Satzes.
  Das Subjekt gibt (zumindest in Aktivsätzen) an, wer oder was der Verursacher der im Satz beschriebene Tätigkeit ist. (*Wer* schiebt?)
- **den Stuhl**
  Das ist eine Nominalgruppe bestehend aus Artikel und Substantiv, die im **Akkusativ** steht und die Funktion eines Akkusativobjekts hat.
  Das Akkusativobjekt des Verbs *schieben* gibt an, welcher Gegenstand geschoben wird.
- **zum Tisch**
  Das ist ein Präpositionalobjekt, bestehend aus einer Präposition (»*zu*«), einem Artikel (»*dem*«) und einem Substantiv, wobei die Präposition und der Artikel zu einem Wort (»*zum*«) verschmolzen sind. Artikel + Substantiv ergeben zusammen ein Dativobjekt. Das ist aber hier bedeutungslos, weil dieses Dativobjekt gemeinsam mit der Präposition eine Einheit bildet, die das Dativobjekt sozusagen abkapselt. Diese Einheit (*zu* + Objekt) ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Grammatisch hat diese Gruppe zwar die Rolle eines Objekts (einer Satzergänzung), kann aber keinem der vier Fälle zugeordnet werden. Insbesondere steht ein Präpositionalobjekt *nicht* im Nominativ und kann daher kein Subjekt sein!
  Eine Präpositionalgruppe, bestehend aus »*zu*« und einem Dativobjekt gibt das Ziel einer Bewegung an. Hier steht also, *wohin* etwas geschoben wird.

Diese drei Bestandteile dürfen sehr frei angeordnet werden. Diese Möglichkeiten sind erlaubt:

> Ich habe den Stuhl zum Tisch geschoben.
>   Den Stuhl habe ich zum Tisch geschoben.
>   Zum Tisch habe ich den Stuhl geschoben.

An Position 1 darf also jede der drei Satzergänzungen stehen. Lediglich die Reihenfolge der Elemente auf den Positionen 3 und 4 kann man aus anderen Gründen nicht umkehren.

Nachdem es nur eine Satzergänzung gibt, die im Nominativ steht (nämlich das Wort »*ich*«), kann nur diese eine Ergänzung das Subjekt des Satzes sein, egal wo es steht. »Ich« ist in jedem der drei aufgelisteten Sätze das Subjekt.